# Unable to set up virtualenv on CentOS for python3

Tags: centos, python, python3, virtualenv

I am using a server that runs CentOS. The default version of python there is 2.7. It also has python3.4 installed.

The package I need to work with requires python3.5. I installed python3.5 but it was a local install (path: /usr/local/lib/python3/5). How do I set up a virtualenv for python3.5?

I am trying the usual

`virtualenv --python=/usr/local/lib/python3.5 .env`

that I use for making python2.7 and python3.4 virtualenvs but I am getting this error:

`The path /usr/local/lib/python3.5 (from --python=/usr/local/lib/python3.5) is not an executable file`

The same command works for python2.7 and 3.4. Is it something to do with the local install?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.5 -m virtualenv env
```

What we are doing here is making sure we are running the specific python3.5 executable you have installed in a local folder and wanted to use and telling it to invoke it's virtualenv module (hence the -m for module).

Tip: In fact you can use the -m  to run all sorts of things like: `python3.5 -m pip --version` and so forth.

Using this technique you can setup virtual environments without touching and of the other python versions that may be on your system or in the system path.